# using array_keys and getting unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is assigned to $elements. When I use array_keys to get the keys, I get what you would expect.

```
print_r(array_keys($elements));
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => anchor-namecontentblock_areaBlock0contentblock11_1
    [1] => anchor-namecontentblock_areaBlock0contentblock22_1
    [2] => anchor-namecontentblock_areaBlock0contentblock33_1
...
```

But when I try to use array_keys with a search value, I get an empty array.

```
print_r(array_keys($elements, "anchor-namecontentblock_areaBlock0contentblock11_1"));
```

Should the result not be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can we have the content of `$elements`?

Comment: Yep! You're definitely missing [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 The array being printed out here is the result of `array_keys($elements)` not the original array. `array_search()` is to search for values, not keys.

Comment: Have `XDebug` set up too.

Comment: @D4V1D From the manual: `Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful` So OP wants to find the key from the value

Comment: @Rizier123 Right, just saw that. My bad, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the wrong array_keys search. Your `anchor-name...` values are KEYS in the original array, not VALUES. As such, your `array_keys` search argument is useless - it'll be searching the values of the original array, e.g.

```
$foo = array(
   'anchor-namecontentblock_areaBlock0contentblock11_1' => 'somevalue'
   etc..
                            searched by array_keys---------^^^^^^^^^^
```

You'd need do something more like:

```
$results = array_search('anchor-name...', array_keys($elements)));
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks MB. Just to clarify though, array_search requires the string as the 1st parameter and the array as the 2nd: array_search('anchor-name...', array_keys($elements));

Answer (score 3):

Specifying a search parameter to `array_keys` allows you to retrieve the key(s) corresponding to one or more **values** in your array. You're passing it one of your array **keys**, so the function is returning no results.